# Transforming EPSG:25831 to EPSG:4326 in Decimal Degrees format

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system, sql

I have a `.txt` file with some x, y coordinates that I assume are in `EPSG:25831`. I want to transform these coordinates to `EPSG:4326` in Decimal Degrees format. Example of one coordinate:

```
x= 539746,19
y= 4743262,723
```

I know that I can run this for transforming the coordinates:

```sql
ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(geocoded_testX.lon_gc, geocoded_testX.lat_gc),25831),4326))
```

But I don't know how to export the table in `.txt` or `.csv` the with the x, y columns in Decimal Degrees format.

Any ideas?

Comment: or you could import the CSV file into QGIS, and then save it as a CSV with a new projection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one line, you can get x and y values and copy to CSV

```sql
\COPY (
SELECT *,
       ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(geocoded_testX.lon_gc, geocoded_testX.lat_gc), 25831),4326))) AS x,
       ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(geocoded_testX.lon_gc, geocoded_testX.lat_gc), 25831),4326))) as y
FROM geocoded_testX
) TO 'file.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

For recipe to import/export CSV in PostgreSQL https://gist.github.com/nepsilon/f2937fe10fe8b0efc0cc

I also used `\COPY` instead of `COPY` as I use `psql`. If you use `COPY`, path will have to be changed from `TO 'file.csv'` to `TO '/your/absolute/path/file.csv'`

Comment: Note that the server side `COPY` can ever only access locations that are owned by the OS PostgreSQL administrator account (i.e. `postgres`, which is not equal to the DB role, but set at installation time).

Answer (score 2):

In the end I did it directly in postgres reprojecting `geom` , creating two new columns and then exporting on .csv using  this sql lines:

```
ALTER TABLE <schema>.<table>
 ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(point, 4326)
  USING ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom, 3857), 4326)

ALTER TABLE <schema>.<table>
 ADD COLUMN "x_4326" float,
 ADD COLUMN "y_4326" float 

UPDATE <schema>.<table> SET "x_4326" = ST_x(geom)
UPDATE <schema>.<table> SET "y_4326" = ST_y(geom)
```